# Mac makefile fatal error: 'armadillo' file not found

Tags: c++, r, makefile, openmpi, armadillo

I am absolutely new to C++ and currently trying to run code from the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/riccardorastelli/NoisyLPM. In particular, I just want to get the R demonstration to work but I think in order to do that I first have to follow the steps of the README file in GitHub.

I am working on a 2021 MacBook Pro M1 and running macOS Sonoma 14.3.

Here some information about the process so far:

First, I installed Homebrew, using the copy-past installation code from their website.

Next, I ran `brew install open-mpi` and `brew install armadillo` to install the required libraries.

Then I used `cd` to change my working directory in the terminal to the `cpp` folder (in which the `make` file is located) and ran `make`.

At first, I was getting the following error: `error: unable to open output file 'obj/main.o': 'No such file or directory'`. Apparently, the `make` file is not creating the folder `obj`, so I created it manually inside the directory and ran `make` again. This time, I get the error `fatal error: 'armadillo' file not found`.

I would be grateful if anyone with C++ experience could help me with this, as I am completely stuck at this point.